# Stop a '+' from generating a formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm having a bit of a struggle. I'm creating a spreadsheet which uses plus signs (`+`) regularly. I want a semi-permanent fix for `+`'s turning into addition formulae.

Comment: [How to prevent Excel from inserting formulas when typing + or - at the beginning of a cell?](http://superuser.com/q/867072/241386)

Comment: [How to force excel to stop thinking your cell contains a formula](http://superuser.com/q/792134/241386)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The easiest workaround is to enter an apostrophe `'` as the first character, right before the `+`.

Another approach is to enter the contents as a string formula like `="+5 blah"`.

An initial plus sign is very much needed for some types of data, e.g.- international phone numbers, so it is unfortunate that even setting the format to plain text does not help here.

Comment: @emmdee, if you try to write only plus sign in the text, the Google Sheets will give you a notification that you need to start the text with an apostrophe to avoid interpreting it as a formula

Answer (score 8):

Do a Find & Replace for = with ' and check "Also search within formulas."

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, worked perfectly for me.

Comment: The only one worked solution to do it in bulk! You can also select required column or fields for replacement.

Comment: Absolutely the best solution. Should be the top answer!

Comment: At first I found this answer really confusing, because it implies that you're going to enter a bunch of data and *then* fix it, but then I realized that some people would end up in this situation *only* because they imported a bunch of data at once. However, this the question doesn't mention importing data, and using this method when you're entering stuff one cell at a time means you would have a messed up sheet for a while. I suspect that is why it got downvoted.

Answer (score 8):

In your Google Sheets select the area and go to **FORMAT -----> NUMBER -----> PLAIN TEXT**. Now the formulas will not work anymore!

Comment: +1 on this. There is a twist, though: You have to do this **BEFORE pasting the offending text** :)

Comment: @ArnaudLeBlanc this does not work unfortunately; before or after adding the format option.

Comment: does not work, neither before nor after

Answer (score 5):

Just add a space before the + sign. Seemed to work for me

Comment: I find this less offensive than having to escape a `+` with a single quote, `'+`

Comment: When you an apostrophe it doesn't get rendered, the space does

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is by adding an apostrophe `(')` before the `+` symbol, as written in [Silver Ringvee's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97312/131658).
However, you can automate it using Google Apps Script.

Here is a simple Apps-Script script I created to solve the problem.
Whenever you edit a cell, it searches through the sheet, and places apostrophe `(')` before the text, i.e. you can simply add +hello, without worrying about adding `'` in the beginning. The script will do i automatically for you.

**Usage-**

Open the sheet, go to `Tools->Script editor`. In the editor that opens, paste the following code. Then add triggers to the script so that the script runs automatically whenever you edit a cell.

*Adding trigger -*

In the editor go to `Resources -> Current project's triggers`. In the box that opens select `Add a new trigger` In column *Run* select `main` function, in *Events* select `From spreadsheet`, then select `On edit` for the last column.

Editor's Note: This code works on cells showing `#NAME?`

**Code -**

```
function columnToLetter(column)
{
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0)
  {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}

function letterToColumn(letter)
{
  var column = 0, length = letter.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    column += (letter.charCodeAt(i) - 64) * Math.pow(26, length - i - 1);
  }
  return column;
}

function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data)
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   for (var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++)
     if(data[i][j]=="#NAME?") {
     var clm=columnToLetter(j+1);
       var rng=clm+String(i+1);
       var range = sheet.getRange(rng);
       var frml = range.getFormula();
       range.setValue("'+"+frml.substring(1));
       Logger.log("sahil#"+frml);
     }
    Logger.log(data[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your application, the following solution could be useful:

Highlight the cell(s) that you would like to appear with a `+`.  Go to the "123" Formatting, choose "More Formats," then go to "Custom Number Format..."

Type `"+"@` into the Custom Format box.  This specifies to add a `+` before the entry no matter if it is a positive, negative, zero, or text entry.

Now, just type in your plain information, and it will appear with a `+` before it.  The problem is that when dealing with formulas, the data will still be shown without the positive sign.

I used https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers&rd=1.

Comment: I would do that, but I also need to use `-` signs as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added a space before the `+`. This worked but I had to remember to trim the values when using them elsewhere. I later discovered that I could simply select the offending cells and go to Data > Trim Whitespace.

Comment: In my case there's no need for computation so I just an invisible character before it (`​`). 
Pro tip: you can copy this character from the HTML editor of the site.

Comment: The 'Trim Whitespace' feature inserts `'` characters. 

Comment: This is very similar to a previous answer -> https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/118868

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is to get the phone numbers in E.164 format to be used in Twilio Google Sheet App. If yes, here is what happened.

What I tried was, put the numbers in column K without the '+' (18889991010), then in the "Phone number" column (which was column A) instead of numbers I put in ="+"&K2, which excel formatted to +18889991010. (Btw, the overall format for column A was Plain Text.

I tried sending the message once, didn't work, tried it again I was surprised it worked.

Here's my status message:

```
sent: Sat Jul 09 2022 08:35:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
sent: Sat Jul 09 2022 08:35:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
sent: Sat Jul 09 2022 08:35:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
error: Exception: Request failed for https://api.twilio.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"code": 21211, "message": "The 'To' number ++1888******8 is not a valid phone number.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211", "... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response).
sent: Sat Jul 09 2022 08:35:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

One number was in E.164 format already in column K, therefore came up with the error. Else worked fine.

I was surprised myself.

Answer (score -2):

There is actually a quite easy solution.

Select the column that contains the + that turns into a formula.

On mac
press [ ctrl + ` ]

On PC (Not 100% sure)
press [ STRG + ` ]

It will still be a formula but wont display Error anymore. Now you can find and replace.

Press command + F to search (Alt + F on PC)

Select the affected column as custom range.

Enter what you want to be replaced under find

Enter a space under replace

Check the box "also check within formulas"

Press find all

Done

Comment: The keyboard shortcut on Mac <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> turns on the **Show all formulas option*, it doesn't "fix" the problem. P.S. It doesn't work on all keyboard layouts.