# Escaping automatic formula with initial + or = in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I want to write a text that starts with a plus sign, but it always interprets it as a formula, and the '+' disappears. I tried specifying 'plain text' format for the cell, but it does not have any effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop a '+' from generating a formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97311/stop-a-from-generating-a-formula)

Comment: Yes, it does answer it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a single quote before the plus sign like:

```
----------------
| '+ blablabla |
----------------
```

Comment: the ‘ symbol doesn’t work. It shows the ‘ symbol after hitting enter.