# How can I comment out parts of a formula in a Google Drive Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

How can I comment out parts of a formula in a Google Drive Spreadsheet?

In PHP you can comment a line of code using a `#` what is the syntax to do the same in a Google Spreadsheet?

I want to use this to temporarily disable a part of a formula rather than write a note / comment.

For instance I have this formula:

```
=QUERY({
'ALPHA'!A6:X70;
'BETA'!A6:X70;
'CHARLIE'!A6:X69
},"select * where Col1 <>''
order by Col24 DESC")
```

I would like to be able to comment out the part:

```
 order by Col24 DESC
```

Comment: You can add `'` before the formula to transform it into a string (I.E. `'=sum(A1:A2)` and it'll display `=sum(A1:A2)` but I'm pretty sure it's impossible to comment inside a formula. [Related](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97311/stop-a-from-generating-a-formula/97312)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the concatenation operator `&` and `IF`

Example

```
=QUERY({
'ALPHA'!A6:X70;
'BETA'!A6:X70;
'CHARLIE'!A6:X69
},"select * where Col1 <>''"
&IF(FALSE," order by Col24 DESC",))
```

Explanation

The formula syntax doesn't include something similar to the PHP `#` comment, JavaScript `//` comment, `/* */` multiple line comment or HTML `<!-- -->`, but you could use functions like `IF`. Another alternative is `IFERROR`. If the formula returns a number, `N` could be another alternative, as it returns `0` when it's argument isn't a number.

In this case I suggest the use of `&` and `IF` because the `QUERY`'s second argument should be a text value. `&` concatenates the two operands and returns a text value; by using `IF` we could set a condition and the value to be returned if the condition is true, in this case `order by Col24 DESC` (please note the leading space), and another value if the condition is false, in this case I suggest to leave the second argument blank, to return a blank.

You could go even further by using a cell reference for the condition to toggle the inclusion/exclusion of the order clause.

Pro-tip: Use Google Apps Script to document and toggle formulas. A cell note or comment could be used to mark those formulas that have being documented this way.

Answer (score -2):

If you are working with Google Apps Script, as when writing macros in Google sheets, you can 'comment out' rows like so:

Use two forward slashes ( // ) to add a single-line comment. Apps Script will ignore all the text following // on the same line.