# Leading with a '+' without starting a formula - but keeping it a number

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97311/stop-a-from-generating-a-formula) is close to what I want, however the answers presented there all involve forcing Google Sheets to recognize the elements as strings. This solution does not work for me, however - the numbers in question are declination values (essentially, latitude, but for astronomy), and I need to run some math with them in other cells. So, keeping them as numbers is important. I'd like to be able to simply input them as, e.g.,

```
+12:34:56
```

(this format is `degree:arcminute:arcsecond`), keeping the leading plus sign (preferably visible), without having Google Sheets immediately add an `=` to the front and then becoming confused when this thing that looks vaguely like a range of cells on the sheet is malformed. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter those declinations as durations of elapsed hours and *format* them to show a leading sign by choosing **Format > Number > Custom number format >**
`"+"[h]":"mm":"ss;""[h]":"mm":"ss;"±"[h]":"mm":"ss`.

The results look like this:

| displayed value | how to enter the value |
| --- | --- |
| -45:26:04 | -45:26:04 |
| -1:34:53 | -1:34:53 |
| -1:03:02 | -1:03:02 |
| -0:31:51 | -0:31:51 |
| ±0:00:00 | 0:00:00 |
| +0:31:21 | 0:31:21 |
| +1:02:42 | 1:02:42 |
| +1:34:03 | 1:34:03 |
| +1:25:24 | 1:25:24 |
| +91:25:24 | 91:25:24 |

Format the entry column as **Format > Number > Duration**. Note that the durations need to be *entered* without a leading `+` or `±`.

Alternatively, enter numbers in a decimal format, and format them like this:

`"+"0.00":"00;"-"0.00":"00;"±"0.00":"00`

The results look like this:

| displayed value | how to enter the value |
| --- | --- |
| -45.26:04 | -45.2604 |
| -1.26:04 | -1.2604 |
| -0.94:53 | -0.9453 |
| -0.63:02 | -0.6302 |
| -0.31:51 | -0.3151 |
| ±0.00:00 | 0 |
| +0.31:21 | 0.3121 |
| +0.62:42 | 0.6242 |
| +0.93:63 | 0.9363 |
| +91.25:24 | 91.2524 |

Note that in this scenario the numbers need to be *entered* without a leading `+`  or `±` *and* without colons `:`.

See [Number format patterns](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_patterns).

Comment: It would be ideal for other cells' formulae if I could keep these in a time-like format (really, duration-like, since the "hours" analog element goes up to 90). Can this method be modified for that purpose?

Comment: Edited the answer.