# How to stop + and - from generating formulas using Apps Script Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

**My Problem**

I have a column of data for users to input text, and it is highly expected that they should add a plus or minus before text, which would result in an error.

For example, they are often shown a string like "+1d4+2", which they are expected to copy and type into the cells, which if they do so, would result in an error.

Typical suggestions such as adding an apostrophe before the + or - sign to prevent the generation of a formula would not work in this context, since users are not expected to understand how to interact with this.

**What I've Already Tried**

*Number Formatting of the Range as Plain Text*

One suggestion was to format the range as Plain Text, but I did not see that this prevented a +/- from generating a formula.

*Apps Script Code*

I saw a code that would look extremely useful posted by a user called Sahil Singh on [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97318/). I followed all the instructions he gave, but when I run the code, it doesn't work because it says 'Column' is not defined. I know how to refer to a range using VBA in Excel, but not in App Scripts.

```
function columnToLetter(column)
{
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0)
  {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}

function letterToColumn(letter)
{
  var column = 0, length = letter.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    column += (letter.charCodeAt(i) - 64) * Math.pow(26, length - i - 1);
  }
  return column;
}

function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data)
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   for (var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++)
     if(data[i][j]=="#NAME?") {
     var clm=columnToLetter(j+1);
       var rng=clm+String(i+1);
       var range = sheet.getRange(rng);
       var frml = range.getFormula();
       range.setValue("'+"+frml.substring(1));
       Logger.log("sahil#"+frml);
     }
    Logger.log(data[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean by *"when I run the code"*. The code should be running from a trigger, you shouldn't be running it.

Comment: Yes, I followed that instruction. Then after it didn't work, I went to the tab where the code was, selected 'Run', and it showed me an error message saying that 'Column' was not defined

Comment: It is intended to be run from an onEdit trigger.

Comment: As I just explained, I did run it that way, it didn't work.

Comment: 1. Please [edit] you question to  explain what didn't work means when you ran it the right way. 2. Include your script  of the version that was run the right way. 3. Include the information from the execution log for the version that was run the right way, so we understand what success messages or error messages were generated.  Running it the wrong way and generating error messages associated with that isn't helpful as that isn't the problem you need help with. I don't see any indication in your script that you ran it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

As you look to be new to Google Apps Script and new to using it to automate Google Sheets, please read thoroughly https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

---

From the question

> I know how to refer to a range using VBA in Excel, but not in App Scripts.

**Google Apps Script** uses **JavaScript** as the programming language. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview.

Note: Please be aware that JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `Column` is not the same as `column`. I mention this because the code includes `column`, not `Column`. When mentioning an error message, please add the textual error.

The error you are getting is likely related to how you run the *script*. The code included in the question looks like it should be run by calling the **Google Apps Script** / **JavaScript** function `main` from the **Google Apps Script** *user interface* or from **Google Sheets** using a custom menu, as a recorded macro, among other options.

The functions `columToLetter` and `letterToColumn` require a value for the `column` parameter. If they are called without assigning a *number* or *letter* (*string*), respectively, an error will be thrown.